# while loop in Mediaplayer from android

Tags: android, loops, android-intent, while-loop, media-player

iam a begginer in android

my code is

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
int f=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MediaPlayer media=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.beep);

    while(f<=3)
{

    media.start();


        f++;

}
```

but in this ,beep is occured only once.(the loop doesn't work).pls help.

Comment: you may have to wait, till it ends and repeat or loop `media.setLooping(true);`

Comment: how to use media.setLooping(true);in my code.

Comment: can i stop use certain condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer media;  
 media=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.beep);
media.setLooping(true);
media.start();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{ 
@Override public void run() 
{ 
if(media!=null && media.isLooping()) 
media.stop(); 
}
 }, 3000);
```

If you have any query, Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer media=null;  
 while(f<=3)
{
if(media!=null)
       {
        media.stop();
        media.reset();           
        media.release();
        media=null();
       }
media=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.beep); 
media.start();
    f++;
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't change the previous output.i dont know why.

Comment: in my code.while debuging loop is working.it beep at  public void stop() throws IllegalStateException.

Comment: beep 3 times while debuging.but not work while running.pls help me to over come this.

Comment: Please edit your answer, explaining why this is a good solution.